# Basic margin reset don't work

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I don't want the default margins so I tried `* {margin: 0}` and the result is weird(it's like a negative value). Actually, the basic reset works just fine until I style my `navigation` class.

**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/gsg/pen/dYGLxX?editors=110)**

```css
header {
  font-family: Hervana, sans-serif;  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: grey;
}

header h1 {  
  padding-left: 1em;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

.navigation a {
  color: black;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block; 
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <header>
    <h1>Logo</h1>

    <nav>
      <ul class="navigation">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header> <!-- END HEADER -->
</div> <!-- END LAYOUT -->
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what your problem is. What is the expected output and how does the current solution differ from what was expected?

Comment: take a look at this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/meVYEM, instead of using * i used the html,body {
  margin: 0;
}

Comment: @feeela - the expected output is in Vinay Singh's pen. Thanks!

Comment: Using Firefox 42+ DE on W7 does yield the expected result with * { margin: 0; }
Are you sure you didn't just have a typo? BTW: flex-direction is not needed as display:flex defaults to row nowrap.

Comment: BTW2: tested it in a plain HTML5 document and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
html,body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

#### [Demo here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/meVYEM)

Instead of using *, also their are a lot of css-reset available to use
my prefferred one is [Css-Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: But why without flexbox `* {margin:0}` works just fine?